# How to install libpcre16.so.0 in ubuntu mate 14.04.5 LTS

Tags: ubuntu-mate

I ask about *libpcre16.so.0* or *libpcre16.so.3* because I want to run Tibia Client 11 for linux. In Tibia Client directory I run terminal and type bash start-tibia.sh and error apear:

```
janek@umate:~/Pobrane/tibia-11.40.5409$ bash start-tibia.sh
/home/janek/Pobrane/tibia-11.40.5409/bin/client: error while loading shared libraries: libpcre16.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I search for fix and find [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QP_fhMSKbpU)

I download *pcre-8.38* from [here](http://www.pcre.org/)  and install from terminal using: `./configure && make && make install` but still don't have needed file to open.

Comment: hmm seems this is supplied by `libpcre16-3` available or installed in 16.04 and later...

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but for future's sake. The issue is you need the following options to configure:

```
./configure --enable-pcre8 --enable-pcre16 --enable-utf --enable-unicode-properties && make && make install
```